# ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '$10592956'

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error

The following is the code snippet. I am trying to append a `$` before the value in the column of a pandas DF. The type of this column is `numpy.int64`.

I get the following error:

> ValueError: invalid literal for long() with base 10: '$10592956'

Tried converting this column to str and `numpy.float64` but none of them works.

```
for i in range(len(adv_new["Col1"][yesterday_date])):
  adv_new["Col1"][yesterday_date][i] = "$" + str(adv_new["Col1"][yesterday_date][i])
```

Comment: It looks like your underlying problem is somewhat different: there is little reason to prepend a "$" in front of a number; you would lose all conveniences such as calculating the sum or the average. Instead, you probably would like to show a $ *only* when printing or otherwise outputting the dataframe. But please correct me if that's the wrong assumption.

Comment: from `str(adv_new["Col1"][yesterday_date][i])` it looks like `adv_new["Col1"][yesterday_date][i]` is not a string datatype but you are then assigning a string "$"+....  to it which is an error. I agree with @9769953 that you should  redesign rather then fixing the code.

Comment: @9769953: So, the only purpose is to add this int value with a "$" sign in an excel. All the calculations have been done earlier

Comment: Can't you modify the formatting of the cells in Excel to have a dollar sign in front of the numbers?